# How can you set an hasMany relationship with limits?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a bit of a weird case and I'm not sure how to handle it.

Let's say I have a bunch of `Containers` and each container `hasMany` `items`, but they only have so many `item_slots`.  For instance, one container could have 3 slots while another only has 1.

```
App.Container = DS.Model.extend({
  name:DS.attr('string'),
  item_slots:DS.attr('number'),
  items:DS.hasMany('item')
});

App.Container.FIXTURES = [
  {id:1, name:'Container 1', item_slots:3},
  {id:2, name:'Container 2', item_slots:4},
  {id:3, name:'Container 3', item_slots:1}
];
```

And then I have a list of `Items` that can go into these slots.

```
App.Item = DS.Model.extend({
  name:DS.attr('string')
});

App.Item.FIXTURES = [
  {id:1,name:'Item 1'},
  {id:2,name:'Item 2'},
  {id:3,name:'Item 3'},
  {id:4,name:'Item 4'}
];
```

I've created a jsBin [here](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/wecikeci/1/edit) as for an example of what I'm trying to do, but it's not complete.  I've commented out the part that I'm stuck on.

I've created a component that provides a drop down of all the different items that can be selected.  My question is really how can I loop over the `device_slots` for each `Container`? Then I can create an `item-selector` for each `device_slot`.

I'm developing the API for this, as well, so if there's anyway I can modify that to help with this issue, that'd be totally possible.  Currently, the payload is something like this:

```
{ "containers":
   [{id:1,name:'Container 1',item_slots:3},
   {id:2,name:'Container 2',item_slots:4},
   {id:1,name:'Container 3',item_slots:1}]
}
```

It use to be like this:

```
{ "containers":
   [{id:1,name:'Container 1',items:[1,2,3]},
   {id:2,name:'Container 2',items:[1,2,3,4]},
   {id:1,name:'Container 3',items:[1]}]
}
```

Until I started really working with it and realized that Ember was automatically relating the Items (which is awesome!).  I tried changing my API so that `items` was just an array with empty strings or `NULL` that I could still loop over with `#each`, but I kept getting an error stating that all items hadn't been loaded. I changed to `item_slots` to avoid the relation issue.

I attempted to create a for loop helper to take care of this, but couldn't quite figure it out.  When I saw that block helpers weren't supported, I felt like I was going the wrong direction.  I've been trying to think of how I could use a view or even a component to accomplish this, but I don't see it.  I have this sort of thing in several places in my app and don't have to have to write tons of specialty classes to handle each case.

Any and all input, ideas and help would be deeply appreciated! Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve the issue, I've added a new blank item to my data set with an id of 0.  Then in my API, I've changed it so that each container returns an array of 0s, one for each slot.  Ember relates that data and I'm able to iterate over them as normal, but because everything's blank, nothing is displayed till I set it with my selector.

Answer (score 0):

First off, I'd like to say that I think your old JSON (with the `items` relationship) was much better. IMO, everything that can be a relationship, should be. Secondly, I think the reason that you were getting loading issues before was because your relationships weren't asynchronous. Try this:

```
items: DS.hasMany(item, { async: true })
```

As for the ability to `limit` a hasMany relationship, you could try overriding the `set` method of the model to check the limit before setting. You could also use Ember-Data's built in validity functionality to invalidate the model if too many are added.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I gave it a try and Ember just tries to fetch the item from the servers instead of returning the error.